# Symfony form redirect to controller instead of route

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Using Symfony 3.4

I have this form in which the user selects a color, and when you submit the form, instead of redirecting to a route, I forward the data submitted to a controller:

```
public function selectColorAction(Request $request)
{



$form = $this->createForm(pickColorType::class);
$form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 

    {
        $data = $form["color"]->getData();
        $getColorId = $data->getId();


        $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:Products:selectPaint', 
        array(
        'color'=>$getColorId,


        )); 
        return $response;
    }

}
```

This is the controller that receives the data submitted from the previous form:

```
public function selectPaintAction($color, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(BrandNameType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
    {
        //something
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Color:enter-brand-name.html.twig',
    array(
     'form'=> $form->createView()
    )
    );
}
```

The problem is that my forwarding not only sends the data, but also the first form, causing an error. The profiler shows both forms: PickColor and the BrandName form. I only want the BrandName after forwarding. What can I do?

Comment: You didn't explained the goal of your implementation. I feel like you decided to go on the wrong path to solve your issue. Can you explain the issue that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

If you look a bit further into what the forward method does:

```
protected function forward($controller, array $path = array(), array $query = array())
{
    $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
    $path['_forwarded'] = $request->attributes;
    $path['_controller'] = $controller;
    $subRequest = $request->duplicate($query, null, $path);

    return $this->container->get('http_kernel')->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
}
```

it clones the current request with `$request->duplicate`.
The duplicate copies the posted values (and other things).

You could try to remove the submitted form data from the request manually before triggering the forward.

Which would look like this:

```
$request->request->remove('THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_FORM_PARAMETER'); 
#what your getBlockPrefix of the PickColorType returns
```

If symfony doesn't inject a clone of the original request into the controllers it should work.